# Why only index scan, where is RID?

Tags: sql-server, execution

I have a task to advice some improvements on the query execution plan. The table is:

```
CREATE TABLE [Contracts] (  [ContractId] [int] NOT NULL  
, [ContractNumber] [varchar](50) NOT NULL  
, [SignDate] [datetime2](7) NULL  
, [EndDate] [datetime2](7) NULL  
, CONSTRAINT [PK_con_Contracts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ContractId] ASC) ); 

CREATE INDEX IX_con_Contracts_ContractNumber ON [Contracts] (ContractNumber) INCLUDE (SignDate)
```

Some values made by me:

```
INSERT INTO Contracts VALUES (1,'12340','2017-10-02','2017-11-02')  
INSERT INTO Contracts VALUES (2,'12341','2017-10-02','2017-11-02')
INSERT INTO Contracts VALUES (3,'12342','2017-10-02','2017-11-02')
INSERT INTO Contracts VALUES (4,'12343','2017-10-02','2017-11-02')
```

Now I am running a query against it:

```
SELECT ContractId  
, ContractNumber  
, SignDate FROM Contracts 
WHERE ContractNumber = 12340
```

and all there comes is a scan of the nonclustered index. But how come? This index doesn't include all the columns I need in the output. I thought that there would be some RID operator to get the columns from the antoher structure.

[image]

Comment: Plus 1 for reproducible example

Comment: You should use `WHERE ContractNumber = ‘1234’` to see a seek.though probably the column datatype is incorrect and should be changed to `int`

Comment: Martin, wow, you are right. I have changed ContractNumber to int, recreated the clustered and non-clustered index and run the query. And it does seek :D. But I wonder why it wasn't able to seek when the column was varchar(50) - you can sort character data, don't you....

Comment: Martin, one more thing. I see your point, to use signle quotes. But what about implicit conversion, doesn't it come into play?

Comment: Martin, you are the one that helped. Thank you.

Comment: Either the ContractNumber is varchar(50) and I search for '12340', or ContractNumber is int and I search for 12340, then seek comes for help :). Thank you Martin.

Comment: I thought that implicit conversion was smart enough but it wasn't

Answer (score 3):

Non-clustered indexes on non-heap tables store the clustered key columns to enable lookup. Here, the clustered key is on `ContractId` and the index is on `ContractNumber` and includes `SignDate` - so this index does include all columns required to satisfy the query.

Comment: Thank you, any advice how to improve it? Maybe force seek?

Comment: I have created a non-clustered covering index and the query uses it, but with scan operation.

Comment: @BartoszSiemasz - until the table contains significant amounts of data, the optimizer isn't going to bother trying to micro-optimize access and will choose to scan.

Comment: And what if the table would contain 11 000 000 rows?

Comment: >>>I have created a non-clustered covering index and the query uses it, but with scan operation<<< The index posted here, IX_con_Contracts_ContractNumber, is ALREADY covering

Comment: >>>until the table contains significant amounts of data, the optimizer isn't going to bother trying to micro-optimize access and will choose to scan<<< If index he's created is like this: (ContractNumber) include(ContractId, ContractNumber, SignDate)  index SEEK will be used

Comment: @sepupic, I can't create index with ContractNumber in both fields. SSMS doesn't allow it.

Comment: : (ContractNumber) include(ContractId, SignDate)  of course

Comment: As I've said, `ContractId` is already implicitly included in any non-clustered indexes on this table since it's the clustering key.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  >>>As I've said, ContractId is already implicitly included in any non-clustered indexes on this table <<< Was it comment addressed to me? And WHY? Did I ever say it's not true? There is no harm to include ContractId as included field EXPLICITELY, it will not be stored twice. But when one day someone decides to turn clustered table to a heap, my index will still include ContractId and the index without it as included column will LOST it

Comment: The reason for the scan is not that the table is too small. It is that the column is varchar and the literal is an `int`. If the query is sargable and can be resolved by a seek on a single range  you will always get the seek rather than a scan *of the same index* irrespective of how many rows in the table

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I want to ask one thing. Why do you refer to primary key ContractId as clustered key? Is it because usage of the "CLUSTERED" clause? Without "CLUSTERED" clause would it be still clustered key?

Answer (score 3):

> But how come? This index doesn't include all the columns I need in the output. I thought that there would be some RID operator to get the columns from the antoher structure.

your query

```
SELECT ContractId  
    , ContractNumber  
    , SignDate FROM Contracts 
    WHERE ContractNumber = 1234
```

needs below columns

```
contractid,contractnumber,signdate
```

even though your nonclustered index has only contract number and signdate,to make it unique ,sql server adds clustered index key  as well  in the non clustered key definition

below is the output from dbcc page to show that

```
DBCC IND('test_log','Contracts ',-1)


dbcc traceon(3604)
DBCC PAGE (0, 1, 195488, 3)
```

[image]

sql server choose this index since it satisfies all columns/index is narrow.Also remember sqlserver optimizer is cost based

Comment: Ok, so currently - with small number of rows - I am ending with scan. If I would have more rows ~2 000 000 then I would end up with seek?

Comment: why do you think so ?

Comment: It is not that "I think so". I am bearing in mind that seek is more efficient than scan. So I am wondering when seek will replace scan in this situation. Under what circumstances.

Comment: @BartoszSiemasz Do not attempt to "solve" a problem you do not have. If you really want to know, then pump some test data into your table and discover the truth yourself. Given the trivially small table you have posted, I'll guess that your real table is more complex as are your queries. So - just try it. There are no absolute answers with respect to indexing and optimization. It is likely that a lookup will eventually be used.

Comment: And one more comment - your contract_id column is varchar but you use a numeric literal. Bad practice that is highly likely (perhaps probable) to cause an error eventually.

Comment: Seek is not efficient than scan and viceversa.Try searching for seek than you scan by Itzik Ben-Gan.Also please try to avoid asking more questions in one question,if you have a question on this,ask a new one